# Is there a more efficient way to mass import files to PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have to mass import a bunch of files which summed up are roughly 1TB. Each file is roughly 150MB.

I have to import all files to the PostgreSQL DB using python.

This is my solution, are there better ways to get this done?

```
import csv
import psycopg2
import os
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="database",
    user="user",
    password="password",
    port="5432"
)

cur = conn.cursor()


def searchFiles(directory='.', extension=''):
    filelist = []
    extension = extension.lower()
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            if extension and name.lower().endswith(extension):
                filelist.append(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
            elif not extension:
                print(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
    return filelist


def importData(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=":")
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO database VALUES (%s, %s)", row)
    conn.commit()

fileList = searchFiles('.', '.txt')

threadPool = Pool(processes=8)

for file in fileList:
    threadPool.map(importData, (file,))
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I would recommend using COPY command. www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html

Comment: One thing that would be faster is to bulk insert many rows instead of one row at a time. Collect several rows into a list and then issue the insert.

Comment: ... or run all the inserts in a single transaction and use prepared statements.